# A fixed position for preview windows

Tags: vim-windows, split, previewing

Is it possible to setup vim to open all preview windows on a specific location. I want them to open on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the following to your [vimrc](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#vimrc):

```
augroup previewWindowPosition
   au!
   autocmd BufWinEnter * call PreviewWindowPosition()
augroup END
function! PreviewWindowPosition()
   if &previewwindow
      wincmd L
   endif
endfunction
```

The [`:wincmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3awincmd) allows you to use the functionality available in normal mode in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. And [`CTRL-W_L`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#CTRL%2dW_L) moves the current window to the far right.

Unfortunately it is not possible to set the preview window size from the quickfix file type plugin -- probably because the cursor doesn't stay on that window.

This approach will trigger for every window (see [`BufWinEnter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufWinEnter)), thus it will add a little overhead.